# Как получить доступ к данным вложенного метода в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть тест:

```
def test_pro_0021(app):
    ...
    app.search360.perform_search(DB(name="john doe"))
```

Есть класс с моделью:

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def people_tab(self, name="name", country="1", state="2"):
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
        self.state = state
```

Есть метод с действиями:

```
def perform_search_tab_people(self, fields):
    wd = self.app.wd
    wd.find_element_by_xpath("my_xpath").send_keys(fields.name)
```

Я хочу разбить модели, чтобы все передаваемые поля не пихать в 1 метод init. Есть ли способ сделать что-то вроде:

```
def test_pro_0021(app):
    ...
    app.search360.perform_search(DB.people_tab(name="john doe"))
```

Comment: __ **init** __ -это не метод, а **конструктор**

Comment: @MickeyU `__init__` не конструктор!

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит обратиться к `Вложенные функции Python`

> https://pythlife.blogspot.com/2012/11/python.html

А если кратко, функции вообще имеют **локальную** область видимости

При вложенности функций, которая **может быть сколько угодно большой**, функции видят только **локальное** окружение и окружение переменных **более высокого уровня**.

Например :

```
def base:
    c=2
    def base1:
        a=2,b=3
```

**base 1** способна видеть все, что объявлено в ней, и все, что объявлено в **base**, при том ,если бы они разделяли одну переменную,скажем `y` , она бы поменялась для обоих функций, с **функциями**(**методами**) ситуация **та же**

Answer (score 0):

Вы всегда можете определить метод класса за его пределами.

```
def myfunc(self, b):
    print(self.arg+b)

class _Class():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.arg = a
    myMethod = myfunc

blah = _Class(5)
blah.myMethod(6)
```

> 11

Здесь вы получаете параметры для метода `myfunc`, определенного вне класса, как из самого экземпляра класса (`a`), так и напрямую как параметр функции (`b`). Только обратите внимание на порядок объявления функции и класса.